# XCode 5: How do I create mutiple projects in workspace?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, git, xcode5

- My experience with `Xcode` and `Objective-C` is 1 day
- I am taking up a course in `iOS` programming where there will be multiple programming assignments
- For each programming assignment there will be one project. I thought to create a workspace which will have multiple projects
- Also, I could then put my workspace on Github. This will help me not creating multiple `git` repositories for each project.

**What I tried?**
- I tried adding files to workspace, but on disk I don't see them under workspace. On `XCode` it seems it creates a reference. Not very helpful.

**What I need?**
- I want to add multiple projects under workspace, not references, actual project directories
- I want to put entire workspace on GitHub (once above is figured, this is simple job)

Please recommend a way of doing this.

P.S. This is my first question in this category

Comment: How about putting all projects in same folder, add them into same workspace, and commit the whole folder to Github?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you ask Xcode to make a new project, it offers you a chance to make it part of an existing workspace. So just do that.

[image]

However, I think the workspace is a total red herring. After all, it isn't a folder. What I do is just make a folder with lots of project folders in it. Lots and lots of project folders. Like this:

https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples